# display the text inside of an image tag

Tags: html, css

Is it possible if I have `<img src='Assets/image.png'>some text</img>` to get the 'some text' to display?

I know I could just use a div and style the div to display on top of the image, but what I want to know is if it's in anyway possible to get the text inside the tag to show up.

Comment: as far as i know, you can not do that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No. There is no text inside the img. According to the specs, the img element is a void element, i.e. it doesn't have any content or an end tag.

The good news is that in your example source, the text "some text" will show up on the page. (It's technically not inside the img, so it is simply displayed directly after.) That's probably not what you want though...

Possible solutions are:

- If you want a text that is displayed instead of the image whenever the image cannot be displayed, put the text inside the `alt` attribute.
- For a text that is shown when the user hovers the mouse over the image, use the `title` attribute
- To display both the image and the text in the page, use a [`figure`](https://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/figure) element in which you put the `img` and put the text inside the `figcaption` and use CSS positioning to put the figcaption on top of the image.

  ```css
  figure {
    position: relative
  }
  figcaption {
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
    line-height: 150px;
    text-align: center;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    text-shadow: 0 0 1px white;
    font-weight:bold;
  }
  ```

  ```html
  <figure>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/150" />
    <figcaption>some text</figcaption>
  </figure>
  ```

Comment: Arlight, thanks!  I think in order to achieve what I want to do I'll need a slightly different approach.

Comment: OK. I edited the answer to add an actual solution. Hope it helps!